# Subject verb agreement for singular and plural subjects

Tags: verb-agreement

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> Was there any insight you had or analytical deductions you made that we 
>   didn't know about?

I'm not sure because "was" should be singular for "insight", but the verb ought to be "were" for "analytical deductions."

Comment: I think you are asking about _any_ this or that, which is singular.

Comment: How about: did you have any insight or make any analytical deductions that we didn't know about?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Should it still be "were" for "any analytical deducations" though?

Comment: I learned that the verb goes according to the proximal noun when a singular and plural are split by "or". "was" is closer to "insight" than "deductions."

Comment: I read the sentence as asking about '_any one_ of this or _one_ of those,' which calls for singular either way. As others explain here, '_was_ any insight' is right due to neighborhood. See Chris M for the sleekest solution from the ground up, by making the sentence more direct to begin with. That's editing.

Answer (score 2):

When  two subjects are combined by the conjunction **or**, the verb agrees in number with the closer subject. If the closer subject is singular, the verb is singular (even if the farther one is plural); If the closer subject is plural, the verb is plural (even if the farther one is singular).

*The room is too crowded, either two chairs **or** **a table has** got to be moved out.*

*The room is too crowded, either a table **or** **two chairs have** got to be moved out.*

> "**Was** there any insight you had **or** analytical deductions you
>   made that we didn't know about?"
>
> The same rule may be applied here.